# Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Excel::selectSheetsByIndex()

Tags: php, excel, laravel, backend, maatwebsite-excel

I am upgrading maatwebsite/excel from v2.0 to v3.0.

```
public function getValidatedRows($uploadedFile)
{
    $validationRules = $this->getValidationRules();

    $sheet = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($uploadedFile);

    $rows = $sheet->all();

    if (!count($rows)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid data.');
    }

    $parsedRows = [];

    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {

        $rowNumber = $key + 2; // Added + 2 since key is zero-indexed and first row is for Headers.

        $columns = $row->toArray();

        $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, count($validationRules));

        if (count($columns) != count($validationRules)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid data.');
        }

        $columnValues = array_values($columns);

        $columnKeys = array_keys($validationRules);

        $columnsWithValidKeys = array_combine($columnKeys ,$columnValues);

        $attributes = [
            'name'   => 'name',
            'email'  => 'email',
            'mobile' => 'mobile',
        ];

        $validationRowSuffix = "(row #{$rowNumber})";
        array_walk($attributes, function (&$item1, $key, $suffix) {
            $item1 = "$item1 $suffix";
        }, $validationRowSuffix);

        $attributes = array_filter($attributes);

        Validator::make($columnsWithValidKeys, $validationRules, [], $attributes)->validate();

        $parsedRows[] = $columnsWithValidKeys;
    }

    return $parsedRows;
}
```

I am unable to upgrade this piece of code `Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($uploadedFile);`

This is how my upgraded export file is looking as of this point.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;

class GenericExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithStrictNullComparison
{
use Exportable;

private $heading, $data;

public function __construct($heading, $data)
{
    $this->heading = $heading;
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function collection()
{
    return collect($this->data);
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return $this->heading;
}

public function properties(): array
{
    return [
        'creator'        => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        'lastModifiedBy' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        'title'          => 'Spreadsheet',
        'description'    => 'Default spreadsheet export',
        'subject'        => 'Spreadsheet export',
        'keywords'       => 'xxxxxxxx, excel',
        'category'       => 'Excel',
        'manager'        => 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'company'        => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    ];
}

}
```

I have already successfully upgraded everything else to v3.0. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) of the maatwebsite\excel.

The above code is where the problem is occurring at the function and the below code is where I have already created an Export file and using it for other purposes such as downloading, writing in excel.

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation regarding [#Conditional Sheet Loading](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html#conditional-sheet-loading) and the `onlySheets()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging a lot I finally found out the answer.

I will be putting the solution to the problem below:-

```
public function getValidatedRows($uploadedFile, $corporate)
{
     $validationRules = $this->getValidationRules();


    $employeeImport = new EmployeeImport;
    $sheet = Excel::import($employeeImport, $uploadedFile);
    $rows = $employeeImport->data;

    if (!count($rows)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid data.');
    }

    $parsedRows = [];

    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {

    $rowNumber = $key + 2; // Added + 2 since key is zero-indexed and first row is for Headers.

    $columns = $row;

    $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, count($validationRules));

    if (count($columns) != count($validationRules)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid data.');
    }

    $columnValues = array_values($columns);

    $columnKeys = array_keys($validationRules);

    $columnsWithValidKeys = array_combine($columnKeys ,$columnValues);

    $attributes = [
        'name'   => 'name',
        'email'  => 'email',
        'mobile' => 'mobile',
    ];

    $validationRowSuffix = "(row #{$rowNumber})";
    array_walk($attributes, function (&$item1, $key, $suffix) {
        $item1 = "$item1 $suffix";
    }, $validationRowSuffix);

    $attributes = array_filter($attributes);

    Validator::make($columnsWithValidKeys, $validationRules, [], $attributes)->validate();

    $parsedRows[] = $columnsWithValidKeys;
}

    return $parsedRows;
}
```

Generic Export File will be used for the export purpose not for the import purpose. For import, you need to make an import file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class EmployeeImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow {

public $data;

public function collection(Collection $rows) {

    $xyz = $rows->toArray();
    
    $this->data = $xyz;
    return $xyz;
}

public function headingRow(): int
{
    return 1;
}
}
```

If you **return anything in the collection function it will not be sent back to the controller**. So, if you want to send the data to the controller you need to make a public variable and then call it in the controller.